# After Hostforweb migration - Order Confirmation Emails are not being sent; Everything else works fine!

Tags: magento-1.9, email, cron, order-confirmation

```
Magento 1.9.1
Aschroder.com SMTP Pro Email Extension
Sendgrid.com
```

We were affected by the Hostforweb recent meltdown (migrating the site to New York having an outage and then being assigned new IP's without knowing and having an extensive outage because of that). It seems that we have gotten most everything working now EXCEPT FOR the Order Confirmation Emails are not being sent.

The way we have this setup is - the Order Confirmation Email should be sent through the "Aschroder.com SMTP Pro Email" extension to Sendgrid and then Sendgrid.com sends the Email on to the customer. The problem is that **Sendgrid never seems to receive the Email in the first place**.

All other SMTP Email works fine. I was even able to send a test message from sales@ourdomain.com (where the Order Email Confirmations come from) to my personal Email address and it worked.

I did a test to see if the cron is working as advised on the bottom of this page:

http://support.magerewards.com/article/1533-setting-up-cron-jobs-in-magento

(Additional Testing to see if CRON is running)

and it made the "cron.php.log" file but NOT the "cron.sh.log" file! (it may have been just me adding the code in the wrong place in the cron.sh file though)

Anyways, any ideas what else may have gone wrong? This is definitely related to the migration from the Chicago to the New York server. Everything worked fine before the migration and never worked after the migration was completed. We were assigned new IP addresses.

Here are the settings from the "Aschroder.com SMTP Pro Email Extension":

```
Email Connection = Customer SMTP
Authentication = None
Host = **127.0.0.1** (what is that?)
Port = 7777 (that should be correct says Hostforweb)
SSL Security = No SSL
```

Here is the modified cron.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
# location of the php binary
if [ ! "$1" = "" ] ; then
    CRONSCRIPT=$1
else
    CRONSCRIPT=cron.php
fi

MODE=""
if [ ! "$2" = "" ] ; then
    MODE=" $2"
fi

PHP_BIN=`which php`

# absolute path to magento installation
INSTALLDIR=`echo $0 | sed 's/cron\.sh//g'`
date >> "$0".log
whoami  >> "$0".log

#   prepend the intallation path if not given an absolute path
if [ "$INSTALLDIR" != "" -a "`expr index $CRONSCRIPT /`" != "1" ];then
    if ! ps auxwww | grep "$INSTALLDIR$CRONSCRIPT$MODE" | grep -v grep 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
        $PHP_BIN $INSTALLDIR$CRONSCRIPT$MODE &
    fi



else
    if  ! ps auxwww | grep "$CRONSCRIPT$MODE" | grep -v grep | grep -v cron.sh 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
        $PHP_BIN $CRONSCRIPT$MODE &
    fi
fi
```

---

*Updated January 8th:*

I guess I'm confused about how this actually works. I thought the cron job was used every time regardless of the "Aschroder.com SMTP Pro Email Extension". If it is not being utilized in our current process then all the better (I don't have to worry about it possibly not working).

The auto-creation of the `cron.*.log-Files` is a method suggested in this article on how to verify the cron.php and cron.sh are running correctly...I added some code to cron.php and cron.sh as suggested by this article and it was suppose to create those `cron.*.log-Files`:

http://support.magerewards.com/article/1533-setting-up-cron-jobs-in-magento

### **The IP reputation thing may actually be the problem because I read somewhere that Hostforweb got some dirty IP addresses which they assigned to their customers in the migration. I have an open ticket with them in regards to being blocked (blacklisted) by AOL. I didn't know we had to have good reputation to send mails to/via SendGrid since SendGrid is the company whose objective it is to help send Email in the first place. I'll try to talk to them even though that may be difficult because they don't really have technical support for their free accounts (our volume qualifies for the free tier at Sendgrid). Is there any way to check this reputation and if that could be the problem?**

*2nd edit on January 8th, 2018:*

I did a lookup on mxtoolbox.com and it says the following:

```
SMTP Reverse DNS Resolution Reverse DNS Resolution - No PTR Record found

SMTP TLS    Warning - Does not support TLS.

SMTP Transaction Time   15.124 seconds - Not good! on Transaction Time


Connecting to my IP address

SendSMTPCommand: Timeout waiting for response after 15 seconds.

KEEPER3v2 15973ms
```

**Is that the problem?**

Comment: `Host` - this is your SMTP mail server. I'm not exactly sure about what your setup looks like but it sounds like a mailing relay? `Aschroder_SMTPPro` would allow you to connect to SendGrid already - why that detour and what's that thing about the `cron.*.log`-Files? 
I'd say you will have to clarify first of all whether you're having troubles with your cron (you may install `Aoe_Scheduler` for checking on this) or with you mails as such (if it's a mailing prob go for the mail logs; Also, a new IP can mean that your server does not have the required reputation to send mails to/via SendGrid)

Comment: @Christoph Farnleitner Thank you for your thoughts. I updated the original ticket (above) with more information. I think you may be right about the IP reputation....it could be the problem! If there was only a way to check that?

Comment: The entries in you mail.log should already give that information. Other possibilities are wrong domain-security related restrictions such as DMARC and SPF - these at least could be tested from here: [MX Toolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/) - an awesome free service to check for (not only) mail-related domain configuration You can also check whether you webserver's IP is blacklisted for example. However, still the first way must go through the logs in my opinion - else I don't see much chance to figure out what the issue is caused by.

Comment: @Christoph Farnleitner I can't find the mail.log file anywhere - I looked at the root level, also in root/logs and root/mail and public_html Where is it usually located?

Comment: Is it even a root or managed server which you got? Or is it some shared hosting? Meaning, do you even get a hand on your mailserver (i.e. postfix or some similar mail server)? If so - logs usually would be located at `/var/log/mail.log`, in case of major troubles entries would be pushe to `/var/log/mail.err` in most setups. Else (i.e. some sort of shared hosting) you gotta talk to your hoster to check on the logs.

Comment: @Christoph Farnleitner This is an expensive VPS server (around $100/month). I have root access (including SSH) but I was trying to look for this mail.log in the root of the account in question (connecting to the via FTP) but I guess it would be better if I connect to the root of the server via SSH?

Comment: @Christoph Farnleitner Also mxtoolbox.com is reporting this - is that the problem?  SMTP Reverse DNS Resolution: Reverse DNS Resolution - No PTR Record found - Reverse DNS Resolution Failed -- SMTP TLS: Warning - Does not support TLS -- SMTP Transaction Time: 15.124 seconds - Not good! on Transaction Time -- Connecting to "IP address"

SendSMTPCommand: Timeout waiting for response after 15 seconds.

KEEPER3v2 15973ms

Comment: SSH is mandatory, yes. PTR is not mandatory but highly recommended. Same for TLS but that's most probably not the cause of your problem. Though, at this point I would recommend you to transfer your problem to https://stackoverflow.com or better https://serverfault.com since I doubt that Magento Community is the best place for this topic. The concentration of experts on server management in these pages is much higher for sure. I'm sorry, though I wish you all the best for finding a solution on this topic!